# Why and where is mvc generating cookies?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I use Visual Studio 2015 and created an empty MVC application with the default controller and default Index action. When I launch my projects 4 cookies are generated: one for the session, one containing I think my country code, one the ip address, and another one containing some data.

I made a breakpoint in the global.asax.cs file at the "Application_EndRequest" eventhandler, but only one cookie was added, the one with the session id.
Where are the other 3 cookies generated? What are their role? And where can I disable them. Even if I delete the cookies in the "Application_EndRequest" eventhandler, they do get downloaded.

Comment: Normally, empty mvc application sets only one cookie and it is for Session. Mvc does not set cookies like you described.

Comment: You were right. MVC does not generate additional cookies. I had some chrome extensions enabled, some cookie and SEO tools, and one of them generated the additional cookies.